# Need help installing Ubuntu on newly-built computer

Tags: ubuntu, usb, boot, motherboard

I just built my first computer, and I need help getting Ubuntu installed.

I downloaded Ubuntu, and put it on my flash drive.

I plugged it into one of the USB ports that is connected directly to the motherboard. For some reason, the flash drive doesn't light up when I plug it into the the USB port that is built into the case; maybe I plugged that into the wrong place on the motherboard.

Then I'll start the machine and hit delete on my keyboard once I see the Bios splash screen to access the UI for Bios. When I go into Bios, I can see an icon labeled USB, so I made that the first Boot devise priority.

Then I restart and do not press delete and received a message that says: Remove disks or other media. Press any key to restart.

So I remove the flash drive and hit F on my keyboard. Now I have a message that says: Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key.

I plugged the flash drive back in a hit F on my keyboard. Now I have the same message: 
Remove disks or other media. Press any key to restart.

Do I have to do something to the USB? Is Ubuntu supposed to be an iso file? Can I use the USB ports that are directly on the Motherboard and which is which? There's six of them and the mouse and keyboard seem to work fine on them.

Answer (score 1):

Did you just copy the iso file to your USB stick?

read: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

There are similar tools for all the operating systems I know, another solution from the ubuntu website: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a tool to install the image from the iso to your flash drive.  Personally I use a tool called Linux Live USB Creator, which runs on Windows: http://www.linuxliveusb.com/